# Eclipse's "Export Runnable JAR" and Maven's "package" command

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

What is the difference between creating a JAR file using Eclipse's "Export Runnable JAR" and creating JAR using Maven's package command? Are the resulting JAR files same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main differences are:

1. Maven gives you programmatic control over exactly how it's built. You can use the assembly plugin or the shade plugin to decide exactly what goes into the jar, where it goes, and how it's all put together. With Eclipse, you have little control.
2. Maven gives you a way of allowing someone else to reproduce what you've done, without needing to reproduce your exact Eclipse setup. In that respect, it's much more suited to packaging open source applications that others will want to compile and build for themselves. It also thereby allows another programmatic process to reproduce what you've done: for instance, a continuous integration server might build your jar and run tests against it before deploying it somewhere.

So Eclipse's export mechanism is really a slimmed down version of what Maven allows.

Comment: Thank you. So if you deploy the JAR file created by eclipse in some application server it will do the same work like Maven's JAR right?

Comment: @Ruby9191 yes, if you haven't got anything too esoteric that would require special maven configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but Maven is "standard" and allow compilation/packaging without Eclipse.

Moreover Maven allows you to customize things like create a source JAR file in addition to the runnable JAR.